# How do I connect redis to Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-session

I want to cocnect the Redis Docker Component to Spring Boot Session. The docker componenet is up and running

```
Steins-MacBook-Air:~ steinkorsveien$ docker exec -it some-redis sh -c "redis-cli"
127.0.0.1:6379> exit
```

To Spring Boot I have in the application.properties file

```
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.password=secret
spring.redis.port=6379
```

I have also added the config

```
package org.steinko.atm;

import org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.EnableRedisHttpSession;

@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class HttpSessionConfig {

}
```

I receive an error when I run gradle bootRun

```
2020-07-06 14:29:15.321  INFO 81198 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-07-06 14:29:15.364  INFO 81198 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-07-06 14:29:15.400 ERROR 81198 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to localhost/<unresolved>:6379
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:893) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.steinko.atm.Domain.main(Domain.java:24) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to localhost/<unresolved>:6379
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getNativeConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-data-redis-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1206) ~[spring-data-redis-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getSharedConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:970) ~[spring-data-redis-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:355) ~[spring-data-redis-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration$EnableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:249) ~[spring-session-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to localhost/<unresolved>:6379
        at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:78) ~[lettuce-core-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
        at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:56) ~[lettuce-core-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
        at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.getConnection(AbstractRedisClient.java:234) ~[lettuce-core-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
        at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:207) ~[lettuce-core-5.3.1.RELEASE.jar:5.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.lambda$getConnection$1(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:115) ~[spring-data-redis-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.getConnection(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:115) ~[spring-data-redis-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getNativeConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1225) ~[spring-data-redis-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:6379
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:589) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:839) ~[na:na]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:4.1.50.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

The dependencies in gradle.build looks like this

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.3.0.RELEASE'
    implementation 'net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:6.3'
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.session/spring-session
  compile group: 'org.springframework.session', name: 'spring-session', version: '1.3.5.RELEASE'
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-redis
   compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-redis', version: '2.3.1.RELEASE'



    testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:spring-mock-mvc:4.3.0'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.3.0.RELEASE'
}
```

How do I fix this error and get connection to Redis?

Comment: hi, how do u solve it? i encounter same error

Answer (score 2):

You need add the below configuration in order to create redis template bean.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisStandaloneConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;

@Configuration
public class RedisConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.redis.host:localhost}")
    private String redisHost;

    @Value("${spring.redis.port:6379}")
    private int redisPort;

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {

        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost,
                redisPort);
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);

    }

    @Bean
    public <T> RedisTemplate<String, T> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, T> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, T>();

        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
        redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();

        return redisTemplate;
    }

}
```

Comment: When I added the configuration . I get the errormessage       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool

Comment: I get the same beancreationexception message. anyone a solution to this?

Comment: @Jake2Finn I have updated my answer which is the actual configuration in my project. I have added redis port and host. Hope it helps

Comment: @Pradyskumar, you use `Jedis`, but @stein uses `lettuce`. These are different Redis clients.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be:

1. make sure the docker port is published, see -p option
2. confirm it working by telnet localhost 6379
3. take a look on the autoconfiguration options in Spring Boot, e.g.
   https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data.spring.data.redis.client-name
4. make sure your configuration matches the client library of your project (lettuce/jedis)